# Calling a function using a string within a ready handler... doesn't work

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function, document-ready

So you want to execute a function whose name is in a string or variable:

```
var fn = "foobar";

function foobar() {
    console.log('say something');
}
```

Answers like this - [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) - say to do this:

```
window[fn](); // outputs 'say something'
```

But... **this** does not work for some reason:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var fn = "foobar";

    function foobar() {
        console.log('say something');
    }

    window[fn](); // undefined
});
```

**This** works, however:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var fn = "foobar";

    window[fn](); // outputs 'say something'
});

/* I'm outside the ready handler */

function foobar() {
    console.log('say something');
}
```

I want to keep my functions inside that ready handler so I don't have to write a bunch of anonymous functions to define `jQuery` as `$`. How do I do that?

---

#### Update

Here's what I'm wanting to do:

```
<div data-control="toggleNext">FAQ</div>
<div>Here's some text that will be hidden until toggled</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    function toggleNext() {
        // add ".js_toggled" to .next() element
    }

    $('[data-control]').each(function(){
        var fn = window[$(this).data('control')]; // <-- this don't werk
        if (typeof fn === 'function') fn(this);
    });

});
```

Comment: If your function is inside the ready handler, it won't be available on window unless you specifically set it as such. but, that's a bad idea anyway, just leave `window` out of it and define your own object local to your doc ready  block.

Comment: Oh, you mean like `window[foobar] = function() {}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is inside the ready handler, it won't be available on `window` unless you specifically set it as such. However, that's a bad idea anyway, just leave `window` out of it and define your own object local to your doc ready block.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var fn = "foobar", methods = {};
    methods[fn] = function () {
        console.log('say something');
    }
    $('[data-control]').each(function(){
        var fn = methods[$(this).data('control')];
        if (typeof fn === 'function') fn(this);
    });
    //methods[fn](); 
});
```

Comment: Hmm, well I wanted to do something like `<div data-control="toggleNext">` and loop through various `[data-control]`'s and translate them into functions... So doing `methods[fn]` seems one-time use.

Comment: Can you show an example? seems like that wouldn't be limited to using `window`

Comment: I thought I'd write out my solution as well. Thanks for the help. This was one of those hard-to-research-what-you-don't-know questions.

Answer (score 2):

@KevinB led me to the answer and I'll give him the accept, but I thought this was worth writing out since I imagine other folks out there would want to do something like this.

Since the `window` object does not include functions declared inside the ready handler (that is, without explicitly calling `window['functionName'] = function() {...}`), you can define a local object and call it instead:

HTML:

```
<div data-control="toggleNext">FAQ</div>
<div>Here's some text that will be hidden until toggled</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var myFuncs = {

        toggleNext : function(me) {
            // add ".js_toggled" to $(me).next() element
        },

        doSomethingCool : function() {
            // you'd better make it good
        }
    }

    $('[data-control]').each(function(){

        var funcName = $(this).data('control'),
            fn = myFuncs[funcName];
        if (typeof fn === 'function')
            fn(this);

    });

});
```

I dunno, am I the only one that finds this useful?